# How to handle button clicks From service in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

when my service start i wanna do-click on button

this my code: my app stop working when i call method From Activity To Service
the button do stop recording

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

// The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
MainActivity mc;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mc = new MainActivity();
    mc.btn.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mc.btn.performClick();
        }
    });
}
```

My previous Code I put it inside OnStartCommend :To stop Recording 
i use another service to start Record and it work good put when i stop record using another service my app stop working, this my code to stop recording

```
recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/amr");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadCastReceiver to handle any action or event outside your service.

Flow bellow:

1. In Button OnClickListener() you sendBroadCast with a custom action 
   Ex:  `static final String ACTION_BUTTON_CLICK = "action.custom.button.click";`
2. You create and register broadcast receiver in service listen above action

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending broadcast. Send a broadcast from the `onClick` of the button and then in the service receive the broadcast and do whatever you like.
For broadcast see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)